# Installing Maven on Raspberry Pi 3 OS Raspbian

Tags: maven, raspberry-pi3

I am having an issue with setting up Maven apache also with setting up the profile path. I've been hit with an error to set up JAVA environment as well. Can anyone give me advice or point me in the right direction

Comment: what error you are getting, while installing java

Comment: Why do you need to setup Maven on a Raspberry 3?

Comment: Sorry I'm not installing Java because all my reading says that pi 3's ship with that installed. I'm trying to set up maven in or with a Java environment. I'm trying to set up project using Alexa I'm going through the steps online but I'm stuck on where I am required to setup maven or mvn. It's saying something about Java environment variables not set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed this guide: 
https://xianic.net/2015/02/21/installing-maven-on-the-raspberry-pi/

However, `/etc/profile.d/maven.sh` did not work for me. I just used `~/.bashrc` (any other file executed on shell init will work as well). You can just follow below steps.

1. `wget https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.6.1/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.1-bin.tar.gz`
2. `cd /opt && sudo tar -xzvf /home/pi/Downloads/apache-maven-3.6.1-bin.tar.gz`
3. `vi ~/.bashrc` -> Add the following lines and save the file.

```
export M2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.2.5
export "PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin"
```

4. `source ~/.bashrc`

And it's done. Now `mvn -v` should give something similar to the following output.

```
Apache Maven 3.6.1 (d66c9c0b3152b2e69ee9bac180bb8fcc8e6af555; 2019-04-04T21:00:29+02:00)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.6.1
Java version: 1.8.0_65, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.14.79-v7+", arch: "arm", family: "unix"
```